# Unneccessary Things to Delets

Tags: python

Do you see any unneccessary code, or code that can be deleted in here? Its not finished...

```
 import random
    import os
    # Shortcut to clear the screen
    c = 'clear'
    # Info about the program
    info = 'This game was developed in xCode, by Solomon Wise. He used Python 3.0.1 to build this awesome game'
    os.system(c)
    # Asks for input
    namein = input("Enter your name: ")
    os.system(c)
    class Player:
        # Stores player info
        Name = namein
        oxygen = 100
        health = random.randint(50, 100)
        defense = random.randint(50, 100)
    # Randomizes the oxygen category
    bonus = random.randint(-5 , 5)
    Player.oxygen += bonus
    # Welcome and info
    print("Welcome to Five Days on Mars,", Player.Name)
    print("You are stuck on Mars for five days, you must survive")
    input("Press ENTER")
    os.system(c)
    # Lists player info
    print("You start out with:")
    print(Player.oxygen, "Oxygen")
    print(Player.health, "Health")
    print("And", Player.defense, "Defense")
    input("Press ENTER")
    os.system(c)
    # Prints the info
    print(info)
    os.system("echo 'He also used the OS Module a lot'")
    class StoreObj:
        # Stores store info
        name = ''
        oxygen = 0
        health = 0
        defense = 0
        price = 0
    class OxygenTank(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Oxygen Tank
        name = 'Oxygen Tank'
        oxygen = random.randint(48, 52)
        health = 15
        defense = 1
        price = 50
    class Rover(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Rover
        name = 'Rover'
        oxygen = 0
        health = 1
        defense = random.randint(48, 52)
        price = 30
    class Apple(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Apple
        name = 'Apple'
        oxygen = 1
        health = random.randint(28, 32)
        defense = 2
        price = 10
    class Flower(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Flower
        name = 'Flower'
        oxygen = random.randint(10, 14)
        health = 1
        defense = 0
        price = 5
    class LaserGun(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Laser Gun
        name = 'Laser Gun'
        oxygen = random.randint(0, 15)
        health = -1
        defense = random.randint(90, 94)
        price = 100
    class Fish(StoreObj):
        # Stores info about the item Fish
        name = 'Fish'
        oxygen = 0
        health = random.randint(48, 52)
        defense = 0
        price = 50
    def store():
        global c
        # List of items bought
        listofitems = set()
        # Provides a budget
        budget = 100
        os.system(c)
        # Welcome Messages
        print("Welcome to the store")
        input("Press ENTER to view the price list")
        os.system(c)
        # Prints price list
        print("Item Name: Price")
        print(OxygenTank.name + ":", OxygenTank.price)
        print(Rover.name + ":", Rover.price)
        print(Apple.name + ":", Apple.price)
        print(Flower.name + ":", Flower.price)
        print(LaserGun.name + ":", LaserGun.price)
        print(Fish.name + ":", Fish.price)
        input("Press ENTER to continue")
        os.system(c)
        # Asks the user what the user would like to purchase
        while budget > 0:
            wtbuy = input("What would you like to purchase? You have a budget of " + str(budget) + ": ")
            # Adds Oxygen Tank's attributes to the Player attributes
            if wtbuy == 'oxygen tank' and budget >= OxygenTank.price:
                print("You have purchased the Oxygen Tank")
                budget -= OxygenTank.price
                Player.oxygen += OxygenTank.oxygen
                Player.health += OxygenTank.health
                Player.defense += OxygenTank.defense
                listofitems.add(OxygenTank.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Adds Rover's attributes to the Player attributes
            elif wtbuy == 'rover' and budget >= Rover.price:
                os.system(c)
                print("You have purchased the Rover")
                budget -= Rover.price
                Player.oxygen += Rover.oxygen
                Player.health += Rover.health
                Player.defense += Rover.defense
                listofitems.add(Rover.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Adds Apple's attributes to the Player attributes
            elif wtbuy == 'apple' and budget >= Apple.price :
                os.system(c)
                print("You have purchased the Apple")
                budget -= Apple.price
                Player.oxygen += Apple.oxygen
                Player.health += Apple.health
                Player.defense += Apple.defense
                listofitems.add(Apple.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Adds Flower's attributes to the Player attributes
            elif wtbuy == 'flower' and budget >= Flower.price:
                os.system(c)
                print("You have purchased the Flower")
                budget -= Flower.price
                Player.oxygen += Flower.oxygen
                Player.health += Flower.health
                Player.defense += Flower.defense
                listofitems.add(Flower.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Adds Laser Gun's attributes to the Player attributes
            elif wtbuy == 'laser gun' and budget >= LaserGun.price:
                os.system(c)
                print("You have purchased the Laser Gun")
                budget -= LaserGun.price
                Player.oxygen += LaserGun.oxygen
                Player.health += LaserGun.health
                Player.defense += LaserGun.defense
                listofitems.add(LaserGun.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Adds Fish's attributes to the Player attributes
            elif wtbuy == 'fish' and budget >= Fish.price:
                os.system(c)
                print("You have purchased the Fish")
                budget -= Fish.price
                Player.oxygen += Fish.oxygen
                Player.health += Fish.health
                Player.defense += Fish.defense
                listofitems.add(Fish.name)
                print("Your budget is now", budget)
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Executes if the user input is invalid
            elif wtbuy != 'fish' and wtbuy != 'laser gun' and wtbuy != 'flower' and wtbuy != 'apple' and wtbuy != 'rover' and wtbuy != 'oxygen tank':
                os.system(c)
                print("That's not an option, type 'item' to buy Item, not 'Item'.")
                input("Press ENTER to continue shopping")
                os.system(c)
            # Executes if the user tries to buy something that costs more than his budget
            else:
                print("You don't have enough money to execute the transaction")
                os.system(c)
            # Executes if the user runs out of money
            if budget == 0:
                print("You have ran out of money!")
                input("Press ENTER to view the items you bought")
                os.system(c)
                print("The items you bought are listed below")
                # Prints items bought
                for item in listofitems:
                    print(item)
                # Prints new user attributes
                input("Press ENTER to view your new attributes")
                os.system(c)
                print("Oxygen:", Player.oxygen)
                print("Health:", Player.health)
                print("Defense:", Player.defense)
                input("Press ENTER to exit the store")
    store()
    def day():
        # Counts the number of days
        daycounter = 1
        while Player.oxygen > 0 and Player.defense > 0 and Player.health > 0 and daycounter < 5:
            global c
            os.system(c)
            # Day messages
            print("This is day number", daycounter, "for you on mars")
            print("You have to survive for five days")
            print("Every day you must perform a task, your actions in this task will determine how long you will survive")
            input("Press ENTER to continue")
            # Attribute subtraction
            os.system(c)
            Player.oxygen -= 3
            Player.defense -= 3
            Player.health -= 3
            # Wager messages
            print("Every day you have a chance to wager some of your oxygen.")
            print("The program algorithim will add a number between -'yourwager' and 'yourwager'")
            wager = input("How much would you like to wager?: ")
            # Executes if the user enters a valid number
            try:
                newag = 0 - int(wager)
                endwag = random.randint(int(newag), int(wager))
                Player.oxygen += endwag
                os.system(c)
                print("Your oxygen level is now", Player.oxygen)
                print("It changed by...", endwag)
                input("Press ENTER to continue")
            # Executes if the user does not
            except:
                os.system(c)
                print("That was not a valid value")
                input("Press ENTER to continue:")
            finally:
                os.system(c)
            tasknumber = random.randint(1, 5)
            if tasknumber == 1:
                explore()
            elif tasknumber == 2:
                alienattack()
            elif tasknumber == 3:
                lookforfood()
            elif tasknumber == 4:
                cleanarea()
            else:
                marsrocks()
    day()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- I really don't like how you spread your classes all over the place. You should place them all near the top. This will force you to write constructors for at least some of them.
- As it stands, the attributes for your classes are class attributes. Meaning if you wanted to buy 2 Fishes, they will both have the same health. But if you wanted each Fish to have their own random health, you have to use `self.health = random.randint(48, 52)` in the Fish constructor instead of `health = random.randint(48, 52)` sitting in the class.
- You should use python's routines for printing to screen and reading input from user instead of using DOS commands and `system()`.  For example,

```
    def _write(s):
       sys.stdout.write(s)
       sys.stdout.flush()

    _write("How much would you like to wager?: ")
    wager = sys.stdin.readline()
```

- You should read the responses to [Python Coding Standards Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356161/python-coding-standards-best-practices).

Comment: Also, there's that thing about using global variables.